# Map sd?/sdd? names to Solaris disk names?

Tags: solaris, iostat

Some commands in Solaris (such as iostat) report disk related information using disk names such as sd0 or sdd2. Is there a consistent way to map these names back to the standard /dev/dsk/c?t?d?s? disk names in Solaris?

Edit: As Amit points out, **iostat -n** produces device names such as eg c0t0d0s0 instead of sd0. But how do I found out that sd0 actually is c0t0d0s0? I'm looking for something that produces a list like this:

```
sd0=/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0
...
sdd2=/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s4
...
```

Maybe I could run iostat twice (with and without -n) and then join up the results and hope that the number of lines and device sorting produced by iostat is identical between the two runs?

Comment: The above script is missing a ending " for the last awk. It should be ($9,1,index($9,"s0")-1)}'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following Amit's idea to answer my own question, this is what I have come up with:

```
iostat -x|tail -n +3|awk '{print $1}'>/tmp/f0.txt.$$
iostat -nx|tail -n +3|awk '{print "/dev/dsk/"$11}'>/tmp/f1.txt.$$
paste -d= /tmp/f[01].txt.$$
rm /tmp/f[01].txt.$$
```

Running this on a Solaris 10 server gives the following output:

```
sd0=/dev/dsk/c0t0d0
sd1=/dev/dsk/c0t1d0
sd4=/dev/dsk/c0t4d0
sd6=/dev/dsk/c0t6d0
sd15=/dev/dsk/c1t0d0
sd16=/dev/dsk/c1t1d0
sd21=/dev/dsk/c1t6d0
ssd0=/dev/dsk/c2t1d0
ssd1=/dev/dsk/c3t5d0
ssd3=/dev/dsk/c3t6d0
ssd4=/dev/dsk/c3t22d0
ssd5=/dev/dsk/c3t20d0
ssd7=/dev/dsk/c3t21d0
ssd8=/dev/dsk/c3t2d0
ssd18=/dev/dsk/c3t3d0
ssd19=/dev/dsk/c3t4d0
ssd28=/dev/dsk/c3t0d0
ssd29=/dev/dsk/c3t18d0
ssd30=/dev/dsk/c3t17d0
ssd32=/dev/dsk/c3t16d0
ssd33=/dev/dsk/c3t19d0
ssd34=/dev/dsk/c3t1d0
```

The solution is not very elegant (it's not a one-liner), but it seems to work.

Comment: You can collapse this all into one (bash) command and avoid any temporary files: `paste -d= <(iostat -x | tail -n +3 | awk '{print $1}') <(iostat -nx | tail -n +3 | awk '{print "/dev/dsk/"$11}')`

Comment: @Tekne Nice one!  You can be even briefer; you don't need tail because you have awk: `paste -d= <(iostat -x | awk 'NR>2{print $1}') <(iostat -nx | awk 'NR>2{print "/dev/dsk/"$11}')`

Comment: i get a `tail [+/-[n][l][r|f]] [file]` if i run any of the iostat commands with tail

Answer (score 5):

One liner version of the accepted answer (I only have 1 reputation so I can't post a comment):

```
  paste -d= <(iostat -x | awk '{print $1}') <(iostat -xn | awk '{print $NF}') | tail -n +3
```

Comment: Use `| tail +3` without the `-n` option with Solaris standard `tail` command. The `-n` option will work with GNU `tail` or the POSIX `/usr/xpg4/bin/tail`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the '-n' switch. For eg. 'iostat -n'

Answer (score 2):

I found the following in the Solaris Transistion Guide:

"Instance Names

Instance names refer to the nth device in the system (for example, sd20).

Instance names are occasionally reported in driver error messages. You can determine the binding of an instance name to a physical name by looking at `dmesg(1M)` output, as in the following example.

```
sd9 at esp2: target 1 lun 1
sd9 is /sbus@1,f8000000/esp@0,800000/sd@1,0
     <SUN0424 cyl 1151 alt 2 hd 9 sec 80>
```

Once the instance name has been assigned to a device, it remains bound to that device.

Instance numbers are encoded in a device's minor number. To keep instance numbers consistent across reboots, the system records them in the /etc/path_to_inst file. This file is read only at boot time, and is currently updated by the `add_drv(1M)` and `drvconf`"

So based upon that, I wrote the following script:

for device in /dev/dsk/*s2

do

```
dpath="$(ls -l $device | nawk '{print $11}')"

dpath="${dpath#*devices/}"

dpath="${dpath%:*}"

iname="$(nawk -v dpath=$dpath '{

    if ($0 ~ dpath) {

        gsub("\"", "", $3)

        print $3 $2

    }

}' /etc/path_to_inst)"

echo "$(basename ${device}) = ${iname}"
```

done

```
By reading the information directly out of the path_to_inst file, we are allowing for adding and deleting devices, which will skew the instance numbers if you simply count the instances in the /devices directory tree.
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in other answers, you can map the device name back to the instance name via the device path and information contained in */etc/path_to_inst*. Here is a Perl script that will accomplish the task:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

my @path_to_inst = qx#cat /etc/path_to_inst#;
map {s/"//g} @path_to_inst;
my ($device, $path, @instances);

for my $line (qx#ls -l /dev/dsk/*s2#) {
    ($device, $path) = (split(/\s+/, $line))[-3, -1];
    $path =~ s#.*/devices(.*):c#$1#;

    @instances =
        map {join("", (split /\s+/)[-1, -2])}
            grep {/$path/} @path_to_inst;
*emphasized text*
    for my $instance (@instances) {
        print "$device $instance\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think simplest way to find descriptive name having instance name is:

```
# iostat -xn sd0
                    extended device statistics
    r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv wsvc_t asvc_t  %w  %b device
    4.9    0.2  312.1    1.9  0.0  0.0    3.3    3.5   0   1 c1t1d0
#
```

The last column shows descriptive name for provided instance name.

Comment: you can also add `-p` to get down to the disk partition/slice.

Answer (score 0):

sd0 sdd0 are instance names of devices.. you can check /etc/path_to_inst to get instance name mapping to physical device name, then check link in /dev/dsk (to which physical device it is pointing) it is 100% sure method, though i dont know how to code it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found this snippet on the internet some time ago, and it does the trick.  This was on Solaris 8:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /dev/rdsk
/usr/bin/ls -l *s0 | tee /tmp/d1c |awk '{print "/usr/bin/ls -l "$11}' | \
sh | awk '{print "sd" substr($0,38,4)/8}' >/tmp/d1d
awk '{print substr($9,1,6)}' /tmp/d1c |paste - /tmp/d1d
rm /tmp/d1[cd]
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation to allow for disk names that are longer than 8 characters (encountered when dealing with disk arrays on a SAN)

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /dev/rdsk
/usr/bin/ls -l *s0 | tee /tmp/d1c | awk '{print "/usr/bin/ls -l "$11}' | \
sh | awk '{print "sd" substr($0,38,4)/8}' >/tmp/d1d
awk '{print substr($9,1,index($9,"s0)-1)}' /tmp/d1c | paste - /tmp/d1d
rm /tmp/d1[cd]
```